# Hive Insert Overwrite Table

Tags: sql, hive, insert, overwrite

I'm new to Hive and I wanted to know if insert overwrite will overwrite an existing table I have created.
I want to filter an already created table, let's call it TableA, to only select the rows where age is greater than 18. Can I achieve this using insert overwrite table?

I'm thinking of writing something like:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE TableA SELECT a.Age FROM TableA WHERE a.Age > = 18
```

there are NA entries in the table I created, but I assume that after I filter this table there will be no NAs in the Age column, right?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Self filtering and insertion is not support , yet in hive.

I would suggest the following steps in your case :

1.Create a similar table , say tabB , with same structure.

```sql
create table tabB like tableA;
```

2.Then you could apply your filter and insert into this new table.

```sql
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tabB SELECT a.Age FROM TableA WHERE a.Age > = 18
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah it definitely helps. Also, if I have multiple Age columns (representing different members in a family) how would I select multiple columns while doing INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE?

Comment: you add whatever logic , a big subquery too after insert overwrite table